# Transparent control flickering on scrolling

Tags: c#, user-interface, background, transparency

I've created an application in C# which has custom buttons. These all have transparent background therefore I enherited from Control and override the CreateParams/OnPaintBackground and added a InvalidateEx function.

Now I need a grid like layout(TableLayoutPanel) which is also transparent. Again I created my own control and override the CreateParams/OnPaintBackground and added a InvalidateEx function. On scroll I see that the backgrounds 'remembers' what he has drawn and therefore I see ghosting (if thats the correct word).
Hooking up the InvalidateEx function to the Scroll event will only make the panel flicker on scrolling.

Is there a way to remove that flicker?

```
public class GridLayout : TableLayoutPanel
{
    public GridLayout()
    {
        this.Scroll += delegate { this.InvalidateEx(); };
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20; //Transparent
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    protected void InvalidateEx()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
            return;

        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
        Parent.Invalidate(rc, true);
    }
}
```

I thought of using WPF but I haven't got experience in that and I need to create this in a couple of days -> Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting DoubleBuffered property to true. DoubleBuffered is a boolean property that "gets or sets a value indicating whether this control should redraw its surface using a secondary buffer to reduce or prevent flicker. Some controls in WinAPI do not expose the DoubleBuffered property. Therefore, you might have to use the **Type.InvokeMember** as I have shown in the following piece of code in which I have taken the DataGridView control as an example.

```
typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember
(
  "DoubleBuffered",
  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
  null,
  myDataGridViewObject, // This is a variable of the object you are trying to set this property for.
  new object[] { true }
);
```

The syntax of Type.InvokeMember is as follows.

```
public object? InvokeMember
(
  string name,
  System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr,
  System.Reflection.Binder? binder,
  object? target,
  object?[]? args
);
```

**Do not forget to add namespaces as needed.**